# chmod: copy permissions (with extended permissions) from one file to another

Tags: chmod

I've got a ZFS filesystem that's shared via CIFS. Somehow, the permissions have got all messed up, to the point where the ownership is all correct but a whole bunch of files have 0000 permissions.

The files which work correctly look like this:

```
-rwx------+  1 guest other 3.8M 2011-05-10 14:58 Presentation.ppt
```

How do I copy that permissions set and apply it across the rest of the files on the filesystem?

**Update**

Thanks for the responses - the problem I have is that a file with 700 permissions for some reason doesn't have the delete permission, when viewed from windows:

[image]

Setting the permission gives the '+' on the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view extended permissions with:

```
$ /usr/bin/ls -V Presentation.ppt
```

This could look like:

```
$ /usr/bin/ls -V Presentation.ppt
   -rw-r--r--+  1 root     staff          0 Feb  3 14:13 file.1
        user:lp:rw------------:------:allow
         owner@:--x-----------:------:deny
         owner@:rw-p---A-W-Co-:------:allow
     user:marks:r-------------:------:deny
         group@:-wxp----------:------:deny
         group@:r-------------:------:allow
      everyone@:-wxp---A-W-Co-:------:deny
      everyone@:r-----a-R-c--s:------:allow
```

You could then apply this set of ACL settings recursively to your share:

```
$ /usr/bin/chmod -R A=\
    user:lp:rw------------:------:allow, \
    owner@:--x-----------:------:deny, \
    owner@:rw-p---A-W-Co-:------:allow, \
    user:marks:r-------------:------:deny, \
    group@:-wxp----------:------:deny, \
    group@:r-------------:------:allow, \
    everyone@:-wxp---A-W-Co-:------:deny, \
    everyone@:r-----a-R-c--s:------:allow, \
    /mnt/share
```

Comment: Once I twigged that my 'ls' command was actually the GNU ls and not the Sun ls, this became a lot simpler. Why the Windows 'delete' permission is a non-trivial ACL, I've no idea.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out the numeric representation:

```
-  rwx --- ---  
0  111 000 000
   --- --- ---
    7   0   0
```

So, if the owners and groups are fine, you can change all the permissions to `700`.

```
chmod -R 700 /path/to/folders
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod -R 0700 /path/to/files
```

Although, the "+" is troubling, indicating a special ACL on the files. you can use `getfacl` and `setfacl` for those, but it's much more complicated. Check out [this page](http://bsdwiki.reedmedia.net/wiki/View_and_modify_ACLs.html) for getfacl/setfacl info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a ZFS guru, but first verify the extended permissions show up with `getfacl <filename>`.  Assuming so, you can use that output for setfacl, which sets the permissions.  Do so by first dumping the access list you want via `getfacl Presentation.ppt > correctfacl.txt`, then setting other files to that with `setfacl -M correctfacl.txt <files_to_change>` (The `-R` flag will make this recursive)

Comment: getfacl gives "File system doesn't support aclent_t style ACL's.
See acl(5) for more information on Solaris ACL support." For the life of me, I cant figure out how to display the extended attributes on these files.